# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'beetwen'

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm getting rhis error when trying to pass date parameters.
does someone knows about it??

```
public List <Object[]>getMontantParVehicule(Date d1,Date d2) {

    Session session=HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    System.out.println("Stat HQL");
    SQLQuery q=session.createSQLQuery("select IMMAT,SUM(PRIX) as          COUT,SUM(QUANTITE) as QUANTITE,COUNT(IMMAT) as nbre from BON_ESSENCE where DATE_BON beetwen     :debut and :fin  GROUP BY IMMAT ");
  //  Query q =session.createQuery("select immat,sum(prix) as mnt from BonEssence group by   immat  ");
    q.setParameter("debut",d1  );
    q.setParameter("fin",d2  );
return q.list();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you've mis-spelled "between" as "beetwen" try this:

```
where DATE_BON between
```